# How to associate certificate information to already signed data?

Tags: java, digital-signature, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pdfbox

I am trying to add digital signature to pdf document using pdf-box library (v2.0.8). I am receiving already signed content from a webservice (signed with only private key). Now I would need to associate certificate information to this signed data so that it can be added to PDF document. How can we add certificate to already signed content, preferably using bouncy castle api ?

```
// here content is data which has to be signed
public byte[] sign(InputStream content) throws IOException {
        try {
            CMSSignedDataGenerator gen = new CMSSignedDataGenerator();
            List<Certificate> certList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();
            certList.add(certificate);
            Store certs = new JcaCertStore(certList);
            gen.addCertificates(certs);

            CMSProcessableInputStream msg = new CMSProcessableInputStream(signPrivate(content));
            CMSSignedData signedData = gen.generate(msg, false);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DEROutputStream dos = new DEROutputStream(baos);
            dos.writeObject(signedData.toASN1Structure());
            return baos.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
```

Here, I am able to generate digital signature, but it does not contain any certificate information. I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38594334/4108540) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10424968/4108540) question but they donot take the case where content is already signed using private key seperatly and only certificate needs to be associated.

Comment: In all CMS signature profiles to be taken seriously you need the certificates in question *before* the signatures are created as a reference to the certificate in question is part of the signed data.

Comment: @mkl, do you mean to say that we can not associate certificate later and it can only be done at the time of signing content with private key ?

Answer (score 1):

(The code you posted refers to CMS signature containers, so I assume we are talking about **adbe.pkcs7.detached** or **ETSI.CAdES.detached** PDF signatures.)

When creating a signature in a CMS signature container, one has the choice whether the signature value really only signs the (hash of the) document data or whether it signs a collection of so-called *signed attributes* (`signedAttrs` in the `SignerInfo` specification) and the hash of the document data is but a value of one of those attributes.

```
  SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    sid SignerIdentifier,
    digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL,
    signatureAlgorithm SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signature SignatureValue,
    unsignedAttrs [1] IMPLICIT UnsignedAttributes OPTIONAL }
```

*([RFC 5652 section 5.3. SignerInfo Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.3))*

All profiles hereof to be taken seriously, though, require that you use signed attributes, in particular they require you to use an ESS signing-certificate ([RFC 2634 section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2634#section-5.4)) or ESS signing-certificate-v2 ([RFC 5035 section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5035#section-3)) signed attribute to reference the signer certificate.

In these attributes, therefore, the association of the signature with its signing certificate is fixed *before* the signature value is generated.

Thus, you cannot freely associate a signing certificate to an already generated signature.